# WP7 HttpWebRequest POST, server returns "{ result: 'ok' }\" in emulator, but "error: NotFound" on device

Tags: http, windows-phone-7, post, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to do a very basic http POST to a web service from my Windows Phone 7 app.  I know the web service works fine because I'm using it for three other mobile platforms.

I've modified the C# example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx

```
    string boundary = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    private void POST_TEST(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Constants.JSON_URL_PREFIX + Settings.Settings.DeviceID + "/inquiry/new/");
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.Method = "POST";

        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
    }

    public void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        postData.Append("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        postData.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"body\"\r\n\r\n");
        postData.Append("test 123");
        postData.Append("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }

    private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        // Close the stream object
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();

        // Release the HttpWebResponse
        response.Close();
    }
```

I'm receiving "{ result: 'ok' }" from the server when I run this in the emulator, but "error: NotFound" when I run it on my Samsung Focus.  I'm assuming this has to do with the way a string is converted to a byte[] on the phone versus a desktop computer.

Any ideas on a fix?  Maybe this is a known error that I never ran across searching the web for an answer?

Comment: Does the request reach the server? can you connect to the server from IE on the device?

Comment: Yes, the request reaches the server.  I know this because I'm getting a response from the server.  It's not just timing out.  Yes, I can connect to the web service in IE on the device.

Comment: if your device (via IE) isn't able to connect to the server then that should be your first point of investigation. If it's not possible to connect from device to server changes to your code aren't going to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out that my phone's Unique ID / Device ID has a forward-slash in it.  This caused a problem when I constructed the web service Uri at:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Constants.JSON_URL_PREFIX + Settings.Settings.DeviceID + "/inquiry/new/");
```

Uri emulator example: http://www.blah.com/abc_123=/inquiry/new/
Uri device example: http://www.blah.com/abc/123=/inquiry/new/

Obviously, it worked fine in the emulator because the emulator's device ID doesn't have a forward-slash in it.  Essentially, the Uri I was trying to post to was incorrect.

Kind of an obscure bug...

Thanks Opena and Matt.  Your suggestions gave me things to try and eventually helped me see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution on an app but my postData looks like `postData.Append("test=123")`. I don't use boundaries (I thought boundaries were only for mails ?)
Also my request.ContentType is `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`